# React-Virftual v2 | Virtualizer `virtualItems` only contains 11 elements although `totalSize` is 20k+

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ui-virtualization, react-virtual

Basically, I'm implementing a virtualized Material UI v4 `Autocomplete`, to do so I have this component:

```js
const ListboxComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLUListElement>(({ children, ...rest }, ref) => {
  const childArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const parentRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const virtualizer = useVirtual({
    size: childArray.length,
    parentRef,
    estimateSize: React.useCallback(() => 50, []),
  });

  console.log({child: childArray.length, virts: virtualizer.virtualItems.length});

  return (
    <div ref={parentRef} style={{height: '500px'}}>
      <ul ref={ref} {...rest} style={{height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
      {virtualizer.virtualItems.map(({ index, measureRef }) => React.cloneElement(
        items[index] as ReactElement,
        {
          ref: measureRef,
          style: {
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: `translateY(${52 * index}px)`,
            width: '100%',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
          },
          "data-start": start,
        }))}
    </ul>
    </div>
  );
});
```

The log outputs: `{child: 267871, virts: 11}`.

I want to understand why only 11 virtual elements are rendered and how can I make that it renders the rest of them.

I'm using `react-virtual` v2, I can't upgrade to v3 nor to use `react-window`, nor any other library.

EDIT 1: I tried using `overscan` but I have the same problem, it renders only the first `overscan` elements but not all of them.

Comment: The purpose of a virtualized list is to deliberately *not* render them all. I suspect what you actually need is to apply styles to the children. The children need a transform (or top) to position them correctly. I can't find documentation for v2 to give an exact example.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have added the `transform` with no luck. Any other idea(s)?

Comment: Can you show that code please?

Comment: @NicholasTower I have edited there.